# How to design scalable containerization of clients from server

Tags: docker, architecture, containers, system-design, scalable

We have client-server application where we are deploying clients on a different machine as a stand-alone application

Client server communicates using REST APIs in a way client also exposes the REST APIs.Now, we have a requirement where we need to deploy client to containers.

One client requires one distinct IP so that client server communication can happen as server communicates client based on client IP or host name registered first time client is started.

Based on that what options can we have and how can we achieve scalable container deployment with automated handling of client scaling from server.

Answer (score 0):

this is an ideal case for service registry and discovery. You can use zookeeper along with synapse and nerve. Please go through this post https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/smartstack-service-discovery-in-the-cloud-4b8a080de619